# Interpretation of header file

Tags: c++, c, lapack, lapacke

I'm trying to discover the meaning of some library linkage and found this in the header:

```
#ifndef LAPACK_GLOBAL
#if defined(LAPACK_GLOBAL_PATTERN_LC) || defined(ADD_)
#define LAPACK_GLOBAL(lcname,UCNAME)  lcname##_
#elif defined(LAPACK_GLOBAL_PATTERN_UC) || defined(UPPER)
#define LAPACK_GLOBAL(lcname,UCNAME)  UCNAME
#elif defined(LAPACK_GLOBAL_PATTERN_MC) || defined(NOCHANGE)
#define LAPACK_GLOBAL(lcname,UCNAME)  lcname
#else
#define LAPACK_GLOBAL(lcname,UCNAME)  lcname##_
#endif
#endif
```

I don't understand what these do, particularly where it is returning the suffixed `##_`

Thanks

Comment: You may get more responses if you split this question individually for each compiler directive that you are confused about. You may not get a response explaining every single compiler directive in the code above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the C preprocessor, `##` is the token concatenation operator. So `lcname##_` can be read as "create a new token by putting `_` at the end of `lcname`".

I presume that the quoted preprocessor code is defining a preprocessor macro `LAPACK_GLOBAL` which is intended to be used as follows:

```
#define LAPACK_something LAPACK_GLOBAL(something, SOMETHING)
```

after which any use of `LAPACK_something` will be substituted by one of the following:

```
something
something_
SOMETHING
```

depending on the environment.